# How to set BarChartDataEntry labels (String not Double) not xaxis labels

Tags: ios, swift, ios5

Hi all i need help i want to format `BarChartDataEntry` labels as shown in image.
[image]

My Code

```
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var dataEntriesBottom: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
     for i in 0..<goals.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(goals[i]))
       dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
     }
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.colors = [.systemGreen]
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartData.barWidth = 0.4
    chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.granularity = 0
    self.chartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    self.chartView.legend.enabled = false
    chartView.data = chartData
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
let myFormatter = NumberFormatter()
myFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
myFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
chartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: myFormatter))
```

Comment: Marked Accepted. One more question? how to rotate these labels?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the code for rotation ready, but you can clone the Charts repo (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and then poke around in the ChartsDemo-iOS project